# I need a reference defining Representation Theorem

Tags: representation-theory

I am doing my research and need a reference in which Representation Theorem is defined.
Albeit not on the web, somewhere valid in researches.

The research is in the field of Continuum Mechanics. Actually I need some reference telling the readers what the Representation Theory is.

One of these theories is, e.g., Representation Theory of Isotropic Functions.

Comment: Which "representation theorem" ?  Perhaps you could tell us where you were looking? Can you guess the statement of the theorem? Also, the web is valid in research, you just have to cite the proper sources...

Comment: @snarski I added some comments.

Comment: So something like this? http://www.maths.bath.ac.uk/~masjs/Research%20Papers/Representation.pdf You might want to put some other tags in the OP then, because "representation theory" will attract a different flavor of answers (though what you are looking for could be thought of as basic representation theory).

Answer (score 0):

I guess I would just take any math book on representation theory and quote its preface, foreword or introduction.

Examples:

Fulton-Harris (second paragraph of the preface): "Representation theory is simple to define: it is the study of the ways in which a given group may act on vector spaces. (...)"

Curtis-Reiner (first sentence of the preface): "Representation theory is the study of concrete realizations of the axiomatic systems of abstract algebra. (...)"